# Url Routing Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing, redirect, querystringparameter

I have a blog page where blogs are fetched from database to my webpage.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="blog_post">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <div class="">
           <img src='<%# Eval("photo")%>' alt="Couple blog image" width="205px" height="150px" /> 
      </div>
                            </div>
                         <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
         <p class="posting_date"><%# Eval("date","{0:MMMM dd,yyyy}")%></p> 
      <h3><a href='ReadBlog/<%# Eval("title").ToString()%>'><%# Eval("title")%></a></h3>
                          <a href="ReadBlog/<%#Eval("title") %>"> <%#Eval("title") %> </a>
      
      <p class="blog_text">
       <%# Eval("sdesc")%>
                            <p class="blog_text">
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" style="color:wheat" href='read_blog.aspx?id=<%# Eval("title")%>'>Read Post</a>
                                </p>
      </p>
       </br></br>
      
                            
                                    <hr/> 
                        </div>
                                    
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

on my Read_blog.aspx.cs page I have used...

```html
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            string myquery = Page.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
         

            cls.gridbind(GridView1, "select * from tbl_blog_master where title='" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + "' order by date desc");
 
        }
```

I want to get the url like this
localhost/readblog/my-first-blog

help me please i am new to asp.net and have to learn a lot...

This is my first time on stackoverflow so sorry for my english..

Comment: Note: never put anything from the user directly into SQL queries. Use parameters for safety.

Comment: Can you please brief it more about this.